# Saving melt output to another avi/mp4 file

Tags: media-player, media, mlt, melt-framework

I am trying to use [mltframework](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt) to merge 2+ videos. I want to generate another .avi file from these merged video files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 29):

Try

```
melt {input-sequence} -consumer avformat:{output-name} acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264
```

Substitute `{input-sequence}` and `{output-name}` to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you share an example or related links for absolute beginners

Comment: Example `melt in1.mp4 in2.mp4 -consumer avformat:output.mp4 acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$ melt    -consumer avformat:
for a basic working example. You may want to set some parameters for avformat so it looks nice.